# Having trouble when selet row in SQL database using python

Tags: python, sql

`con=sqlite3.connect('D:/Aegle Intern/Michael Files New/Sim.db')`

`cursor=con.cursor()`

`cursor.execute('''select * from tbl_exprt_sim where member_count={} and spec1_trigger={} and sl_trigger={} and policy_effective_date={} and state={}'''.format(member_count[i],spec_trigger[i],sl_trigger[i],PED[i],S[i]))`

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BETzx.png)

[Error Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kngV6.png)

The above screenshots are the problem I met. As you can see, I want to select all columns from a table with column state="Michigan". And I want to use .format method or similar methods to deal with this searching, because "Michigan" is an element in a list. (probably replace .format('Michigan") with something like .format(S[i])).

Please offer some helps! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Error Reason may be this that your format word is string. But you pass only {} that represent integer.
Please Replace your {} with '{}' this.

try this

```
cursor.execute("select * from tbl_exprt_sim where state='{}'".format('Michigan'))
```

copy all code for better result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This do solve my problem.

Comment: Unlikely to be a security issue in your personal case. However, it should be mentioned that this approach (string formatting) exposes a well known security vulnerability called ‘SQL injection’. Definitely worth some research to understand the risk to which you have exposed yourself.  A more robust (correct) approach is to use *parameterised queries*. Also worth doing to research in this subject.